# Passing parameters from C# application to Python application [for using in gensim] in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, python, visual-studio-2017, parameter-passing, gensim

I am a C# programmer and new to Python. Now I am working on Python form Visual Studio 2017.

I have already written a program in C# to do some text processing tasks, but now I need to accomplish my work in python as it provides advanced functions for dealing with Natural Language Processing.

Specifically, I need to pass a `List<List>` parameter from my C# application to the Python application.

The passed parameter will be used instead of `doc_term_matrix` inline 48 at the following python snippet:

[image]

Another issue to be handled is the casting of the different data types, as I want to import a `List<List<double>>`, as shown below, from C# to be used as the parameter returned from the `dictionary.doc2bow(doc)`  function in Python.

[image]

I have no idea how to do so. So, please help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with python and I don't know whether this would work for you, but have you had a look at https://pythonnet.github.io/

From a brief glance it looks like you might be able to import your assembly and use methods / properties directly in your python code

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I will read it and see if it may help.